# How to update particular cell value in spark data frame?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframe. I need to find a value from a dataframe and update a cell for a particular row.

Ex.

```
Df1 = (a, 10), (b, 20), (c, 30)
Df2 = (a, A1), (c, C1)
```

Expected output:

```
(A, 10, A1), (b, 20, NaN), (c, 30, C1)
```

Please send me in the solution in details as I have just started to work with spark dataframe.

Comment: Spark DataFrames are immutable, so technically you cannot update any values. What you'd have to do is create a new dataframe with the values you want using some transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
val d1 = Array(("a", "10"), ("b", "20"), ("c", "30"))
val rdd1= sc.parallelize(d1)
val df1 = rdd1.toDF("key","val")

val d2 = Array(("a", "A1"), ("c", "C1"))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(d2)
val df2 = rdd2.toDF("key","div")

val res = df1.join(df2,Seq("key"),"left_outer")
res.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result in two steps.

- first, a `leftOuterJoin` that will give you a pair RDD with pairs like `(a, (10, A1))`
- second, with a simple `map`, you can transform the pairs into the expected results